# Expectation of the exitpoint distance for the symmetric random walk

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, random-walks, martingales

Let $\nu(x)$ be a symmetric probability measure with respect to the origin on $x\in[-1,1]$ such that $\nu(\{0\})\neq 1$.

Consider a random walk started at $S_0=0$, denoted $S_n=X_1+\dotsb+X_n$, where $X_1,X_2, \dotsc$ are i.i.d. random variables such that $X_i\sim \nu(x)$.

Fix $1\leq L<\infty$, and put $\tau=\inf\{n\geq0: S_n>L\}$ and $\hbar_{\nu,L}=\mathbb{E}(S_\tau)-L$.  In other words, $\hbar_{\nu,L}$ is the mean value of exitpoint distance from $L$.

**My question is how to derive the explicit formula for $\hbar_{\nu,L}$.**

Maybe one can start by fixing $L = 1$ and choosing some simple $\nu(x)$, say with probability density function $\mu(x)$ given by

1. $\mu(x)=1/2$, $x\in[-1,1]$ or
2. $\mu(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{1-x^2}$, $x\in[-1,1]$.

Could you recommend some relevant papers or books for me?  Anyway, any hints or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use math mode for formatting.  For example, `** **` forces bold in Markdown, and Markdown natively supports enumerated lists; neither should be faked with an equation environment.

Answer (score 1):

If we denote the density $d\mu/dx=p(x)$ (considered  as a function on the whole line), for the function $f(L)=\hbar_{\nu,L}$ (also considered on the whole line) we get $f(L)=-L$ whenever $L<0$ and $$f(L)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)p(L-t) dt,\quad L\geqslant 0.$$
This is Wiener--Hopf equation for the function $f$ on $[0,\infty)$, and on first glance your problem (in full generality) does not seem to be much less general than general Wiener--Hopf equation.

Answer (score 1):

The question you ask is studied by the renewal theory (Feller, *An introduction to probability theory and its applications*, vol. 2, Chapter XI or Asmussen, *Applied probability and Queues*, Chapter V). The function $f(L)=E S_{\tau(L)} - L$ solves the so-called renewal equation (written above by Fedor Petrov), and it follows from the renewal theorem that $f(L)$ has a limit as $L \to \infty$ (Asmussen, eq. (V.6.3)). However, the value of this limit involves $f(0)= E S_{\tau(0)}$ and $E S_{\tau(0)}^2$. If your distribution is atomless, it follows from the symmetry assumption (Feller, Section XVIII.5) that $f(0)=\sqrt{E (X_1^2)/2}$, and it seems that a similar formula should be available, with an effort, for $E S_{\tau(0)}^2$.

Moreover, the distribution function $F(x, L) = P(S_{\tau(L)} - L<x)$ satisfies the renewal equation for every fixed $x\ge 0$. The renewal theory implies that there is a limit distribution for $S_\tau - L$ as $L \to \infty$ with the explicit distribution function (Feller, Sec. XI.3). The expectation of this distribution is the limit for $f(L)=E S_\tau - L$, the quantity you are up to.

Nothing specific can be said for fixed $L$ in general case. The following known relation gives a way to think about $f(L)$ for a fixed $L$:
$$P(\tau(L)> n) \sim (f(L)+L) \sqrt{\frac{2}{E (X_1^2) \pi n}}, \qquad n \to \infty.$$